# Why does "(oddNumber And 1) = 1" evaluate to true?

Tags: vb.net, syntax

This is probably a basic question, but I have never used this syntax before. Can someone tell me in detail how this expression evaluates to true? [Assuming IsOdd is a boolean type] Thanks.

```
Dim i As Integer = 3
IsOdd = (i And 1) = 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3 is binary `11`, 1 is binary `01`

```
01 and 11 = 01
```

And 1 = 1

See [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz3k228a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for a reference of bitwise operators.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So how would you determine whether a binary number would evaluate to 001? For instance, how would this expression handle the number 4, for instance? Do I have to have a thorough understanding of binary numbers to understand this?

Comment: Consider that a value of 1 can be represented as an infinite series of 0 and a 1 at the end. All of those zeroes, affected with any bit value (0 or 1), will always give 0, because "0 And 0 = 0", and "0 And 1 = 0". So only the last bit is significant. You can test it thoroughly if you want to make sure, but this line of code effectively determines whether the number is an odd number or not.

Comment: Another example: Consider decimal `204 And 170`.  In binary, that's `11001100 And 10101010`.  Where both numbers are 1 you get 1, and if either is 0, you get 0, so you get 10001000.  In decimal, that's a result of 88.  So `204 And 170 = 88`.  That's how bitwise operators like `And`, `Or`, `Xor` and `Not` work.

Comment: @Matthew to really understand this, you need a reasonable understanding of binary integers and the bitwise AND operator. (It gets more complicated if you need to consider negative numbers.) If you don't have time to fully understand it, you can treat it as a magic expression that's True for odd numbers and False for even numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're assigning a value of 1 at the end of the statement.

Comment: That's not true (see marc's answer)

Answer (score 0):

The `And` operator performs a boolean `AND` operation; if the low bit (1) is set on the value to compare (`i`), then the number is odd.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Dim i As Integer = 3
Dim IsOdd As Integer
If (i And 1) Then
    IsOdd = True 
Else 
    IsOdd = False
End If
```

Hope it helps.